# how to run a function using a variable from anothe function

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How can I use a variable from one function as an argument to another function.

for example :
lel.txt contains text = jack

```
#!/bin/bash

funA(){

export lol=$(cat /home/ubuntu/lel.txt)

}

funB(){

echo "My name is $abcd"
}

funC(){

funB $lol

}

funA
funC
```

The output will be as `My name is jack`

Can someone please help me.

Comment: Please rephrase your question to make it clearer: Do you ask how to use the _output of one function_ as an argument to another function, or how to use _a variable defined or assigned in one function_ as an argument to another function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument of a function is stored in `$1`.

```bash
funB() {
    echo "My name is $1"
}
```